# Detect face from ip camera using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am trying to use an IP camera to detect faces by opencv(python) by 192.168.1.36:8080 url. I can connect to a mobile camera (Ip camera) perfectly but openCV cannot detect faces.
When I use laptop camera everything fine but by Ip camera, I cannot detect faces. 
It's my code:

```
import dlib
import cv2

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.40:8080")
color_green = (0,255,0)
line_width = 3
while True:
    ret_val, img = cam.read()
    # rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    dets = detector(img)
    for det in dets:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(det.left(), det.top()), (det.right(), det.bottom()), color_green, line_width)
    cv2.imshow('my webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break  # esc to quit
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/nima-s-h/PycharmProjects/FaceRecoUsingDlib/FaceDetector.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       cv2.imshow('frame', frame) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion
>   failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot detect faces" ? dets is always empty or you get an error ?

Comment: @emlot77 I forgot to say my error, look again please

Comment: It seems that the `cv2.VideoCapture` has not been initialized correctly due to an invalid URL, thus returning an empty frame. The `img` variable should be `None` and `ret_val` should be `False` in this case. Replace `while True:` with `while cam.isOpened():` and see if the error is still there.

Comment: I solve this problem by rtsp://192.168.1.4:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp url. but I opencv cannot detect face

Comment: Now the video stream is good but you have empty dets? Did you check that the input image in the function detector(img) is correct ?

Comment: check in your loop if your cam isOpened...and display the image. your error says that there is no image to be displayed in imshow

Comment: Dear @emlot77 video stream is fine but opencv could not find face, It dosent work

Comment: @Y.AL yes, you right. It return false

Answer (score 0):

Try this address:

```
http://192.168.1.40:8080/abc.mjpg
```

instead of

```
http://192.168.1.40:8080
```